# how to use ios device as nfc card in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, nfc, core-nfc

I need to make Iphone as NFC card in my flutter app but not getting any helpful resources. Please help. I searched for core nfc for IOS but found only for nfc reader solution not to make device as a card.

I have searched many resources but not get any exact solution.

Comment: This is called "host card emulation".  iOS doesn't support it.  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128931